# Seller Admin Panel for E-Commerce Website?

Tags: e-commerce, admin

I am developing an E-commerce website, I identify that there will be three high-level users:

1. Admin
2. Seller
3. End User

I understand the flow of the Admin and End user but I want some more clarification on Seller Admin Panel, So if anyone knows about this please share your comment or link with me.

Thanks.

Comment: Join shopify, etsy, and amazon seller central and see what they do.

Comment: we already did that. :)